# Please explain how I can make this higher order function work

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, decorator, higher-order-functions

I am trying to understand how `enhancers` or `high order functions` work in JavaScript and how I can compose functions to deliver a decorated functionality.

So I have a basic `user` factory function:

```
function user() {
  return {
    name: 'amit',
    age: 41
  }
}
```

Now I want add authentication behavior like a mock `login` method to this factory. So I write this enhancer

```
function authUser(fn) {
  fn.login = () => {
    return 'you are now logged in'
  }
  return fn
}
```

Now I pass `user` into this enhancer

```
let loggedInUser = authUser(user)
```

But when I try to call the `login` method like this...

```
loggedInUser().login()
```

I get

```
Uncaught TypeError: loggedInUser(...).login is not a function
```

I understand that I am not really calling the fn being passed into the enhancer and that is why probably I am not getting the behavior I want.

- But where do I call it? and
- how do I correctly enhance the original `user` object with a login method or add more properties to it after definition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you're actually assigning `login` property to function `fn`, not the returned value of `fn`. You can try calling `loggedInUser.login()` instead of `loggedInUser().login()` to see the result.

Answer (score 1):

user **loggedInUser.login()** instead of **loggedInUser().login()**,

[image]